# Query to match on array input

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have a collection that has entries with this schema:

```
{
    "_id" : "5966edbfca08e4e92c6484f0",
    "comment" : "....",
    "demographics" : [ 
        "596066467e492a9b1944a988"
    ],
}
```

I also have a form that generates this array:

```
[ { name: 'Age', value: '596066467e492a9b1944a988' },
{ name: 'Gender', value: '595dc5e856207969bd4a2081' } ]
```

I'm trying to figure out a MongoDB query that returns an array of matches in the collection where the "value" in the form array results is in the array in the "demographics" mongo entry. If there are multiple matches, it should match with an "or".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `"demographics"` field is purely and "array of ObjectId" or at least similarly constructed data, the only thing you really need to do here is coerce your input into simply an array of values and match.

The [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator is basically the shorthand form of [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) as applied to a single field. So it takes and array of values as it's argument to be considered for match against the specified field. Also MongoDB does not make any distinction between an "array" or a "singular property" in regards to equality matching within query forms.

But the basic transformation to simple values, simply requires usage of [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var input = [
  { name: 'Age', value: '596066467e492a9b1944a988' },
  { name: 'Gender', value: '595dc5e856207969bd4a2081' }
];

var query = {
  "demographics": { 
    "$in": input.map(i => ObjectId(i.value) )
  }
};

collection.find(query)
```

Assuming of course that your actual data is in `ObjectId` format and not "strings", but any actual "form input" from a HTTP request will always be presented as "strings" and would need to be cast to the correct types in order to match where the types differ.

Some libraries such as [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) will actually "cast" the values for you, either by "presumption" that a supplied value is in fact an `ObjectId` or by inspecting an application defined "Schema" for the data, as is the case with mongoose itself. In these cases there is no need to "cast" the data yourself, since it will be done automatically when the query is issued.

The results here of course are the documents where "any" of the values supplied matched "any" value of the `"demographics"` property within the document.